# Hide or display according to a drop down value

Tags: java, ajax, struts2

I'm having a drop down and when I choose one from the field beneath, it must be disappeared. How am I supposed to do this. I'm new to struts. Please help me

```
<td>
    <s:select
      headerKey="none" headerValue="Select UI Controller"
      list="UiControllersMap"
      name="uiController"/>

    <s:fielderror fieldName="uiController" cssClass="customErrorMessage"/>
</td>
```

Comment: If you want to hide the SELECT after selection, I'm pretty sure this is not a best practice. What if the user click by mistake ? He can't undo the selection anymore ? Can you be more specific on what you are trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure from your question which field needs to disappear: dropdown or label below? Let's assume label.

```
<td>
    <s:select
      id="dropDownId"
      headerKey="none" headerValue="Select UI Controller"
      list="UiControllersMap"
      name="uiController"
      onchange="hideField()"  
      />

    <s:fielderror id="fieldId" fieldName="uiController" cssClass="customErrorMessage"/>
</td>
<script language="text/javascript">
   function hideField() {
      dropDown = document.getElementById("dropDownId");
      fieldError = document.getElementById("fieldId");
      if (dropDown && fieldError) {
         if (dropDown.options[dropDown.selectedIndex].text == fieldError.innerText) {
            fieldError.style.display='none';
         }
         else {
            fieldError.style.display='';
         }
      }
   }
</script>
```